# unexpected display in Floyd triangle

Tags: java, stdin

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
class sa
{
public static void main(String args[])
 {
int i,j,caunt=1, k,m=1;
System.out.flush();
try
{
 k=(int)System.in.read();
 while (caunt<=k)
  {
  for(i=m;i<=m;i++)
    {
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
   {
  System.out.print(caunt);
  ++caunt;
   }
  System.out.print ("\n");
    }
++m;
 }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
 }
}
```

this program is intended to display ployd triangle when i give input 10 it should display 
like

```
1
23
456
78910
```

but it's showing

```
1
23
456
78910
,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,55
```

please help me

Comment: The char `'7'` has the int value of **55**. Which `read()` delivered to `k`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this line:

```
k=(int)System.in.read();
```

The problem is that you are reading in a character and not a number like you expect.  I would do the following instead of the above line:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
k=stdin.nextInt();
```

I have tested it, and this works.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
int i, j, caunt = 1, k, m = 1;
System.out.flush();
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
k = stdin.nextInt();
while (caunt <= k) {
    for (i = m; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(caunt);
            ++caunt;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    ++m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read() only reads a single byte